# Python PIL cut off my 16-bit grayscale image at 8-bit

Tags: python, image, tiff

I'm working on an python program to display images of stars. The images are 16-bit grayscale tiffs.
If I try to display them in an extern program, e.g. ImageMagick they are correct but if I load them in python and then use 'show()' or implement them in a canvas in Tkinter they are, unless a few pixel, totally white.
So I estimate python sets every pixel above 255 to white but I don't know why. If I load the image and then save it as tiff again, ImageMagick can show it correct.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Version 1.1.6 My PIL can handle my images but the display is just wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the image to a numpy array and display that:

```
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('image.tiff')
arr = np.asarray(img.getdata()).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0])
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.show()
```

You can change the color mapping too:

```
from matplotlib import cm
plt.imshow(arr, cmap=cm.gray)
```

Comment: im usign python 3, Image no found